# formatting combobox elements

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, formatting

In my database serial-numbers are stored as an **Integer**.
I want to represent these numbers in a Access-frontend combobox with a different formation:

- "121212345" --> "12.12.12345"

When a number is chosen it should be stored as an Integer again.

I already tried to populate the combobox by myself with some **VBA** code:

1. use a query to select all numbers
2. iterate all numbers and convert each to the new formation
3. put each converted number in the combobobox

When a selection is made i use the **afterUpdate-Event** to convert it back to an integer value and store it in my table.

This approach works very well but populating the combobox takes very long (4 sec for 20.000 numbers).

Is there a faster way of doing it?

When i just use the plain integer-field as recordsource, the box is populated in no time.

**Edit:**

```
'populate Combobobox:

Set db = CurrentDb
strSQL = "SELECT intSerialNumber FROM tblXXXX"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

Do While Not rs.EOF
    strCurrentSerNum = rs.Fields(0).Value
    Dim strSerNum As String

    'xxxxxxxxx to xx.xx.xxxxx when possible
    If (Len(strCurrentSerNum)) = 9 Then
        strSerNum = Left(strCurrentSerNum, 2) & "." & 
        Mid(strCurrentSerNum, 3, 2) & "." & Right(strCurrentSerNum, 5)       
    Else
        strSerNum = strCurrentSerNum
    End If

    cboSerNum.AddItem (strSerNum)

    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Please post the code that you are using to iterate over the integers and modify them for presentation in the view. Also include the code that retrieves the data.

Comment: i have edited my post with some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Input Mask property for this.

A valid input mask to achieve exactly what you want is the following:

`##.##.#####;;`

Comment: thank you very much. this works for the presentation of a selected value in the combobox and the manual input. but when i expand my combobox all values are still displayed without dots. i can live with that.

Comment: I can fix that, but the answer will get substantially longer (and slower) if I do. If the answer provided the desired effect, please accept it.